# Maven 3 dependency resolution fails until maven-metadata-local.xml files are deleted [maven-invoker-plugin related]

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-3

In one of my Maven projects, dependency resolution will succeed once, then fail for later build attempts:

```
[WARNING] The POM for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.4 is missing, no dependency information available
```

…and so on, *until* I delete the `maven-metadata-local.xml` files corresponding to the failing artifacts (e.g. `~/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/maven-metadata-local.xml`).  After those files are deleted, the next `mvn` invocation proceeds properly; the metadata files are restored by that invocation (presumably as part of the process of checking my upstream repositories/mirrors for updated artifacts), and I am again presented with the above errors until I again delete the metadata files.

This impacts multiple projects, though it appears to be limited to a particular set of dependencies.  I suppose I could go nuclear and blow away my local repo, but I'd like to understand what the problem is.

Thoughts?

**Update:** It looks like it's the [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) (which these builds are using for general-purpose integration testing) that is producing these `maven-metadata-local.xml` files.  I'm not using an integration-testing-only local repo [as described here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/install-mojo.html#localRepositoryPath), simply because doing so causes the re-downloading of all transitive dependencies ([unless you want to maintain an integration-specific settings.xml file!!!](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/fast-use.html)).  I've used the invoker plugin with a variety of other projects in this way with good results -- certainly never encountering a wedged local repository in the process like this.

**Update 2** OK, this is repeatable, even after starting with a completely fresh local repository.  This is on OS X, Java 1.6.0_24 with Maven 3.0.3; note that Maven 2.2.1 does **NOT** exhibit this problem.

Here's one of the projects in question: the [1.3.0-compat branch of rummage](https://github.com/cemerick/rummage/tree/1.3.0-compat).  To reproduce:

```
> mvn clean test
# no error -- can run this and other builds that don't involve maven-invoker-plugin all day w/o problems
> mvn clean integration-test
# FAIL: "Could not resolve dependencies", with warnings as noted above
> mvn clean test
# FAIL: "Could not resolve dependencies", with warnings as noted above
```

Once the local repository is borked (by the generation of the `maven-metadata-local.xml` files, AFAICT), no builds will get past the dependency resolution stage.

Running `mvn -X` reveals lines like this for each artifact that is later apparently not found:

```
[DEBUG] Verifying availability of /Users/chas/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.4/mail-1.4.4.jar from []
```

Of course, `/Users/chas/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.4/mail-1.4.4.jar` et al. *does* exist, as does `/Users/chas/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.4/mail-1.4.4.pom`.  Totally puzzled.  At this point, I'm assuming this is a bug in Maven 3 (or some underlying library), now that I see that 2.2.1 is clean.

**Update 3** [Bug report filed with Maven project](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5087).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is resolved in aether 1.12, one rev above the aether 1.11 library that ships with Maven 3.0.3.  Replacing aether 1.11 with 1.12 in one's Maven install results in expected behaviour ([as noted in the bug I filed](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5087)).  Here's hoping Maven 3.0.4 is released with aether 1.12 ASAP. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you do not mention what you may have tried, so maybe you didn't try this one: adding the -U option to force update ? (tho maybe this -U option is only relevant for SNAPSHOTs ...)

Comment: Yes, -U only checks for SNAPSHOTs AFAIK; that said, yes, I tried it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar errors caused by corrupted files in my local repository. For example, if a download failed partway through, or a file in a remote repository changed after I downloaded it. Deleting the affected directories under `~/.m2` fixed it.

Comment: Blowing away my repository does not resolve the issue; it is repeatable from a totally clean local repo.  Notes added to the main question's description, along with a link to a public project's branch that is affected.